# Waiting for promises in different methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

I'm currently struggling with promises and I think I got the concept a bit wrong. Basically what I am trying to do is writing a little template handler.

It has a load() method which loads a template and stores it into a property and it is going to be chainable. The method I want to chain it with is `attachTo()` with appends the template I loaded before to a DOM element.

Since the template is loaded asynchronously I tried to use promises. But it seems that the `done()` method on the promise is firing immediately, and before the async call has been finished.

I call it like that:

`tpl.load('stuff.html').attachTo($('.someElement'));`

What I want it to behave is, that whenever I call `attachTo()` it will wait for my previously called load() method to get it's asynchronous stuff done, and then fire the callback provided in the `done` method.

Here's the relevant part of the handler

```
var tpl = {
...
    template: null,
    promise: null,

    load: function(template) {
        this.promise = $.get(this.templateUrl + template, function(response){
            this.template = response;
            console.log(this.template);
            //Outputs the desired value
        });
        return this;
    },

    attachTo: function(el) {
        var self = this;
        $.when(this.promise).done(function(){
            //outputs null but should output the 
            //value that has been set in my async call
            console.log(self.template);
        });
    }

..
}

tpl.load('stuff.html').attachTo($('.someElement'));
```

Comment: This looks just OK, maybe you are receiving an error (done is invoked regardless of the result type). Try the this.promise.then().fail() approach to tell apart from good request results from bad ones.

Comment: Thanks @PeterAronZentai. Indeed it was my mistake. When I set the template property I am messing up the scope. This does not refer to my object anymore but instead to the scope of the callback. Just had to use proxies. Thanks for pointing out that issue!

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem with your code _at the moment_ mind clarifying?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's already solved see my above comment :) But sure. The problem was that I thought the `done()` method on the promise was fired bevor the async request in my `load()` method was processed, since my `template` property was empty although it should have been filled by the ajax request in the load method. Eventually it turned out it was just a scoping problem and had nothing to do with the deferreds.

Comment: If it's already solved - instead of editing it in please revert the question to its original status and post an answer on how you solved it.

Comment: It was never modified (I just added a comment but this was when I still hadn't solved the problem). Thanks though. I'll added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have identified the problem yourself already, the proposed solution is not a good one.

You should not use global variables that are set somewhen and use promises just for propagating changes, but the promises should *represent* these values. This leads to a better, functional programming style.

In your case:

```
var tpl = {
    …
    templatePromise: null,
    load: function(template) {
        this.templatePromise = $.get(this.templateUrl + template).then(function(response) {
            console.log(this.template);
            //Outputs the desired value
            return response;
        });
        return this;
    },
    attachTo: function(el) {
        $.when(this.templatePromise).done(function(template) {
            // get the template here:              ^^^^^^^^
            console.log(template);
        });
    }
    …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it was a scoping problem. There was nothing wrong with the deferreds but with the scope of the instance I assigned the value to.

```
load: function(template) {
    this.promise = $.get(this.templateUrl + template, function(response){
        this.template = response;
        console.log(this.template);
        //Outputs the desired value
    });
    return this;
},
```

Here I assigned a value to `this.template`. But I was not in the scope of my object but in the scope of the closure of the `$.get()` method. Hence other methods cannot pull the value out of the property because it was never stored there.

I came up with:

```
load: function(template) {
    var self = this;
    this.promise = $.get(this.templateUrl + template, function(response){
        self.template = response;
    });
    return this;
},
```

I first assigned the object instance instance to the `self` variable and refered to it inside the closure instead of using `this`. To solve it more elegantly also a [`$.proxy()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) could have been used.

That's all. It was just a scoping and not a deferred issue.